# How to set inflaterInputStream.Position?

Tags: c#, stream, inflate, sharpziplib

I'm trying to set inflater.Position by calling the code below:

```
    Stream data = Compress(buffer);  // data: length=12, position=12
    //inflater: length=0, position=12
    InflaterInputStream inflater = new InflaterInputStream(data);   
    inflater.IsStreamOwner = false;

    // move forward:
    inflater.Dispose();
    data.Position = 0;  
    inflater = new InflaterInputStream(data);     // inflater.position=0
    inflater.IsStreamOwner = false;
    byte[] buff = new byte[newPos - Position];
    while(newPos > Position)
         int count = inflater.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);  //inflater.position=12
```

Right now, when I try to move forward, the Position always stays at its original value.  Is it because whatever length I put in Read method, the method always reads the entire stream, thus position = end of stream?  How may I set inflater.Position?

Follow up:  Why is inflater has a length of 0?  Does it have anything to do with CanWrite property being false?

Comment: I'm actually shocked you didn't get a `NotSupportedException` ("InflaterInputStream Position not supported") exception. It is not intended to be setable.

Comment: I developed a MovePosition method for the setter.

Comment: My guess then: that's where your bug is.

Comment: I'm confused then. Is the code above the actual `MovePosition` method called from the `InflaterInputStream.Position` property setter? Are you modifying the `InflaterInputStream` source directly or is it some subclass you've created?

Comment: Yes, the code above is called by the setter.  I created a new class and this Position property overrides.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok, then how do you set the position variable tracked by the superclass (returned by the getter) here? I'm betting it's `private` and not being set at all.

Comment: Right, but `Stream` doesn't actually implement those; they're abstract: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.position.aspx . **You**, as a subclasser, must provide an implementation.

Comment: position does change through the code, if that's what you meant.  it's set to 0 and then goes back to the end of stream

Comment: Do you have any idea why inflater has a 0 length?

Comment: Fraid I don't know, sorry. Doesn't look to be the case, perusing the source here: http://web-tools.googlecode.com/svn-history/r6/documentation/_inflater_input_stream_8cs-source.html